# How to get owner's photo in custom record page?

Tags: lightning-web-components, record, user-record, owner, lightning-record-page

I made a custom record page, where I can get detail info about records. This includes the owner field. And next to the field I want to get a photo of the owner and maybe user's photo from "Created By". But I don't know how to do this.

What I have:
[image]

What I want:

[image]

My html form:

```
<template>
    <div class="container slds-card_boundary slds-var-p-around_x-small">   
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiName} record-id={recordId}>
            <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
                <template for:each={fields} for:item="f">
                    <lightning-layout-item key={f.Id} size="6" class="slds-var-p-around_xxx-small">
                        <lightning-output-field field-name={f.name} class="field"></lightning-output-field>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </template>
            </lightning-layout>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>     
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You need to retrieve `SmallPhotoUrl` field from User object and display it in a `<img>` tag.

Comment: yeah, I made this. I get only an image. But I need to understand how I can place an image next to his field. It's hard because I have a loop for fields iterating. How I can find this field?